# Registered symbol not displayed properly from sql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have saved some text in a mySQL Database.

`(field collation is utf8_unicode_ci     but I also tried with latin_).`

When displayed in my HTML is shows a questionmark sign is a box (error, missing icon). The HTML file is `utf-8.` It's not the font since when I write it manually in the document it shows it, either with `&reg; or $#174;`

I've done this a million times and don't know why this happens now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

after mysqli connection established in php use

```
mysqli_set_charset ($db, "utf8");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Have that already